# Import SockJS as AMD in Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, amd, sockjs, ember-cli

I am desperately trying to include SockJS via Bower in Ember CLI.
I have followed the docs as close as I could. These are the steps, which seemed to almost work:

- added `"sockjs-client": "0.3.4"` to `bower.json`
- ran `bower install`
- added the following to `Brocfile.js`

  app.import('vendor/sockjs-client/lib/index.js', {
    'sockjs': [
      'sockjs'
      ]
  });
- added `import { SockJS as SockJS } from 'sockjs';` to my module. I had tried `import SockJS from 'sockjs';` and various other combinations as well...

This at least seems to compile and `ember server` runs without errors. However, as soon as I open the page in a browser, I receive the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: SockJS is not defined`

The created source, which shows the error,  looks like this:

```
SockJS = (function(){
              var _document = document;
              var _window = window;
              var utils = {};

<!-- include lib/reventtarget.js -->
<!-- include lib/simpleevent.js -->
<!-- include lib/eventemitter.js -->
<!-- include lib/utils.js -->
<!-- include lib/dom.js -->
<!-- include lib/dom2.js -->
<!-- include lib/sockjs.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-websocket.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-sender.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-jsonp-receiver.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-jsonp-polling.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-xhr.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-iframe.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-iframe-within.js -->
<!-- include lib/info.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-iframe-eventsource.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-iframe-xhr-polling.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-iframe-htmlfile.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-polling.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-receiver-eventsource.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-receiver-htmlfile.js -->
<!-- include lib/trans-receiver-xhr.js -->
<!-- include lib/test-hooks.js -->
                  return SockJS;
          })();
```

What is the right way to include SockJS with Ember CLI?

**EDIT**

After some more trial and error I got the following working from a browsers perspective:

Brocoli.js:

```
app.import('vendor/bower-sockjs-client/sockjs.js', {
  'sockjs-client': ['sockjs-client']
});
module.exports = app.toTree();
```

bower.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "~1.3.0",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "qunit": "~1.12.0",
    "ember-qunit": "~0.1.5",
    "ember": "1.5.1",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.1",
    "loader": "stefanpenner/loader.js#1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims#0.0.2",
    "ember-load-initializers": "stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "^0.0.1",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rjackson/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.2",
    "bower-sockjs-client": "0.3.4"
  }
```

And **no** import whatsoever within the module.

This makes Ember CLI complain a lot: `'SockJS' is not defined.` However it at least works for now. Is there anything wrong with what I am doing or is this a bug within Ember CLI?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the import doesn't include any of the actual sockjs files, just the index.js

Comment: I edited the question with something that at least seems to work for now, even though it feels wrong. Is there any way to include the missing files through config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you already got this solved. But here is an explanation of whats going wrong. I was also having issues, so I thought I'll see whats going on under the hood.

The library you downloaded via bower "sockjs-client" does not contain the distribution file. You will need to to build it your self. For this you need the `make` command. If you are linux or mac, you already have it. If on windows, you need to download `cygwin` or `mingw`

To build sockjs, go to vendor/sockjs-client/ in the terminal and execute the command

```
npm install
make build
```

This will generate 2 files sockjs.min.js and sockjs.js.

Now you can include this file in your Brocfile.js

```
app.import('vendor/sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js');
```

Now `SockJS` should be available as a global variable. The package you are using now 'bower-sockjs-client' is just a fork that shares the dist files. If you are using that, make sure it is up to date.

Since `SockJS` is a global, you need to add it to the `jshintrc` file.

```
{
  "predef": {
    "document": true,
    "window": true,
    "Demo1ENV": true,
    "SockJS": true
  }
}
```

**Why import is not working -**

The reason you are not able to import the package is because SockJS uses some kind of UMD syntax for amd. They do the following check to see if it can use the amd syntax.

```
typeof define == "function" && define.amd
```

ember-cli uses a minimal loader.js to load amd modules and `define.amd` is not set, so it will evaluate to false in the above code. Even if you modify the loader.js file, the amd definition of SockJS isn't compatible with the ES6 transpiler. ES6 transpiler expectes the module to be exported to the 'default' key.

```
import sockjs from 'sockjs';  will become something like
var sockjs = _dependency_1['default'];
but SockJS is _dependency_1, _dependency_1['default'] will be undefined.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great explanation. I didn't actually solve this, I just found an ugly workaround :) Is there any way to use Ember CLI to automate the step to execute the make command?

Comment: I tried your suggestions and found a few things: The build needed `npm install` before the `make build` command. After that I can import SockJS the way you mentioned, however ember CLI still complains: `myapp/adapters/application.js: line 58, col 26, 'SockJS' is not defined`. How do I get rid of the the ember CLI errors? As for the import statement, it probably would be possible to use the `import sockjs as SockJS` statement? I haven't tried this though...

Comment: Yes you need to  use 'npm install'. I forgot to mention that. The error message you get should be from jshint. ember-cli uses jshint to make sure we dont accidentally pollute the global namespace. So if you intentionally put something in global, you need to add that variable to the .jshintrc file. I've updated my answer with the npm install and jshint code. At the moment, you cannot import the package without modifying the amd loader and transpiler. Look into bower postinstall for automating the build of sockjs. Try filing an issue with the ember-cli project, they might look into this.

Comment: Thanks, this makes things a lot clearer. Seems like there is still quite some work about the AMD compatibility going on.

Answer (score 1):

Given that SockJS doesn't have proper module loading support, I just put the following in my Brocfile

```
app.import('bower_components/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs-1.0.0-beta.12.js');
```

and then at the top of my controller, I have

```
import Ember from 'ember';
let SockJS = window.SockJS;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues so I developed an addon for Ember adding expected sockjs syntax etc.

[ember-sockjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-sockjs)